# Configure Nginx as a reverse-proxy which forward all requests

Tags: nginx

I got a task to use Nginx as a reverse proxies to all requests, so if someone is going through the proxy and the SNI is [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) the Nginx will access [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) fetch the data and provide it to the user, but I need it to all domains and not just some.
Is it something Nginx can do?

Tnx,
Omer

Comment: This sounds more like a forward proxy. You may be better off with software designed for the purpose, such as Squid.

Comment: The Nginx is a requirement (: